# Decomposition of a representation of SU(N) into representations of SU(N-1)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, induced-representations

Let $\omega_k$ be the highest weight of the $k$-th antisymmetric representation of $\mathfrak{su}(N)$.  Consider an irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{su}(N)$, characterized by its highest weight $\omega = \sum_{j=1}^{N-1} n_j \omega_j$ for some integers $n_j\geq 0$.

What is the decomposition of this representation into irreducible  representations of $\mathfrak{su}(N-1)$?  I suspect that there will be $\prod_{j=1}^{N-1} (n_j+1)$ pieces labelled by integers $0\leq k_j\leq n_j$, with highest weights
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{N-1} \bigl(k_j \omega_j + (n_j - k_j) \omega_{j-1}\bigr)
$$
Am I right?

I've obviously failed to find the answer by looking online, and will be very grateful if someone finds a reference for me to read.

Comment: It's useful to search Math Overflow for "branching rules", including the link http://mathoverflow.net/questions/148888/what-is-a-good-introduction-to-branching-rules-in-representation-theory